# On a particular proof of "if the sharp of every real exists and every club contains a club constructible from a real, then $\delta^1_2 = \omega_2$"

Tags: set-theory, constructibility

I am referring to the proof of (4) implies (1) in Theorem 3.16 of Woodin's *The Axiom of Determinacy, Forcing Axioms, and the Nonstationary Ideal*. His proof leverages on the fact that if the sharp of every real exists, then $\delta^1_2 = u_2$, where $u_2$ is the second uniform indiscernible (the least ordinal above $\omega_1$ which is an $x$-indiscernible for every real $x$).

This is roughly how it goes:

- Fix any ordinal $\alpha$ strictly between $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$, and a well-ordering $<_{\alpha}$ of $\omega_1$ of ordertype $\alpha$.
- Find a club $C$ of $\omega_1$ such that for every $\gamma \in C$, the rank of $<_{\alpha}$ restricted to $\gamma$ is less than the least ordinal in C greater than $\gamma$.
- By hypothesis, there is a $D \subset C$, $D$ a club of $\omega_1$, such that $D$ is constructible from a real $z$. We can assume $D$ is definable from $z$ and $\omega_1$ in $L[z]$ since $z^\sharp$ exists.
- By reflecting the definition of $D$ downwards, we have that for every $\gamma \in D$, $rank(<_{\alpha} \restriction \gamma) < rank(\mathcal{M}(z^{\sharp}, \gamma + 1))$, where $\mathcal{M}(z^{\sharp}, \gamma + 1)$ stands for (quoting Woodin) "the $\gamma$[$+1$] model of $z^{\sharp}$". I am not exactly sure what that quote means, so I assumed $rank(\mathcal{M}(z^{\sharp}, \gamma + 1))$ is the least $z$-indiscernible above $\gamma$, which works for the arguments hitherto. Did I make a mistake in my interpretation here?
- Now, following the previous inequality of ranks, he immediately concluded that $\alpha < rank(\mathcal{M}(z^{\sharp}, \omega_1 + 1))$, which finishes the proof.

It is at the last step (the final bullet point) that I got lost. How does $\alpha < rank(\mathcal{M}(z^{\sharp}, \omega_1 + 1))$ follow from the previous steps?

EDIT: Alternatively, I would appreciate it if anyone can point me to another proof of the statement "if the sharp of every real exists and every club contains a club constructible from a real, then $\delta^1_2 = \omega_2$"

Comment: I think what's involved in the last step is indiscernibility. Since the Silver indiscernibles w.r.t. $z$ form a club, you have the next-to-last bullet point for some indiscernibles $\gamma$, and you can replace such a $\gamma$ with $\omega_1$ in any statement that $L[z]$ understands. This replacement will turn $<_\alpha\upharpoonright\gamma$ into $<_\alpha$.

Comment: But we do not know if $<_{\alpha}$ is constructible from any real, so the set of inequalities in the penultimate bullet point may not be expressible in L[z]. Or am I mistaken here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\kappa$ be a sufficiently large regular cardinal. Take a countable elementary substructure $H$ of $H(\kappa)$ containing $z$ and $<_\alpha$ with $\omega_1\cap H\in D$. Let $\pi : M\to H(\kappa)$ be the inverse of the transitive collapse of $H$. To see the fifth bullet point, it suffices to show that in $M$, $\pi^{-1}(<_\alpha)$ has rank less than $(\text{rk}(\mathcal M(z^\#,\omega_1^M+1)))^M$. But this follows from the fourth bullet point since $\omega_1^M = \omega_1\cap H \in D$, $\pi^{-1}({<}_\alpha) = {<}_\alpha \restriction \omega_1^M$, and $M$ correctly computes $\text{rk}(\mathcal M(z^\#,\omega_1^M+1))$ since $z^\#$ is in $M$.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation!